# Does freemarker <#include> go through the templatecache

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I am using Java FreeMarker for templates. Does freeMarker's <#include> directive go through the template cache or does it load it fresh.

Does it matter if parse=false, does that still go through the template cache, as it really is not treated like a template in that case?

Example: <#include "/common/navbar.html" parse=false>

Answer (score 0):

`#include` (and `#import`) always goes through the template cache. Even if `parse=false`.